# How to display who modified the page without having people presence?

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage

I want to display who modified the page without having people presence.

The below code works but I just want to display the name without people presence.

```
    <SharePointWebControls:FormattedString FormatText="{0} and {1:dd-MMM-yyyy}" runat="server">
  <SharePointWebControls:UserField FieldName="Modified By" runat="server" ControlMode="Display"/>
  <SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="Modified" runat="server" ControlMode="Display"/>
</SharePointWebControls:FormattedString>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to List Settings.
Click on the person field or fields.
Notice that the Show Field item defaults to **Name (with presence)**, but includes many additional options. Change it to **Name**.
Press OK.